# How Could a VSTO Project be a Class Library?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsto

Visual Studio usually says "Project with output type of class library cannot be started directly".  So why is it that VSTO projects are class libraries and they work just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Because they set the Start Action to launch a separate EXE (Office).

That error just means that you can't select "Launch Project".

Comment: Nice!  Where can I see that setting?

Comment: Project Properties, Debug tab.

Comment: "Start Project" is selected, not "Start external program".

Comment: Then it's probably a custom project type.